# Passing ARCore GPU Texture to Mediapipe

Tags: android, arcore, mediapipe

I’m working on an application that detects objects with detection+tracker model (mediapipe) and sets anchors on detected objects (ARCore and Sceneform).

Current implementation:

1. Acquire `Image` from ARCore `Frame` in `Scene.OnUpdateListener.onUpdate` method
2. Copy image buffer to byte array and convert to RGB Bitmap using RenderScript
3. Pass it to Mediapipe graph through `FrameProcessor.onNewFrame(bitmap, timestamp)`

Is there any way to avoid copying and converting image to bitmap and pass ARCore GPU texture to Mediapipe graph directly?